# Can sections be applied in Footer of Webi Report

Tags: business-objects

I am in a situation where I need to apply section in my Report Footer. But it is not happening. If anyone have gone through such situation please help me...

Thanks

Niki

Comment: Did you want section details, for example the section heading, to appear in the footer or are you asking if you can add a section to a footer?  If the later I don't think it is possible, but can check tomorrow.

Comment: Sections can't be applied to report footers, but if you can explain your actual requirement we may be able to suggest a solution.  (I'm not sure why there are two close votes, this is a clear, pointed question).

Comment: @ Lima : I need the section applied value to be on the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and sections cannot be applied to report footers.

Comment: I need the section applied value to be on the footer.

Comment: I have had a look and cannot see if this can be done, I found =ReportFilters(object), however in my test report it simply listed all of the values for the dimension I used for the object.  Perhaps someone else can provide further insight but I don't think it is possible.